# Python/SQLAlchemy - Need to delete all the records(from one of the two tables)returned from an inner join query

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, inner-join

I'm using Postgres 9.2 and I need some help converting this query to Python.This query works just fine when run manually.Appreciate any help with this.

The query and the tables are in this fpaste.
http://fpaste.org/62726/

```
'Mail' table:

message "Hello from NYC",
origin  10453,
Length  20

'cities' table :

name NYC, 
state NY,
zip  10453


select * from mail t1 inner join cities t2 on t2.zip = t1.origin  where (t2.state = 'NY');
```

Query 1)

```
session.query(db.mail).join(db.cities, db.cities.zip == db.mail.origin).filter(db.cities.state == 'NY').delete()
```

With this statement,I get this error

```
self = <sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2.PGDialect_psycopg2 object at 0x605b1d0>, cursor = <cursor object at 0x5ebc908; closed: -1>
statement = 'DELETE FROM mail WHERE cities.state = %(state_1)s', parameters = {'state_1': u'NY'}
context = <sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2.PGExecutionContext_psycopg2 object at 0x64c0dd0>

    def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
>       cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
E       ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) missing FROM-clause entry for table "cities"
E       LINE 1: DELETE FROM mail WHERE cities.state = E...
E                                            ^
E        'DELETE FROM mail WHERE cities.state = %(state_1)s' {'state_1': u'NY'}
```

Query 2)

```
session.query(db.mail).join(db.cities, db.cities.zip == db.mail.origin).delete()
```

This  works fine,in that it deletes all the records from 'mail' where cities.zip == mail.origin,but at the moment,I need to get Query 1)working.

Comment: Please add some more detail here. What have you tried so far? Include your code and any errors it's producing.

Comment: I've edited my question.Could someone take this off hold?Thanks.

Comment: Could someone let me know why this is still on hold?Thanks.

Comment: Using a [`subquery`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.subquery) worked for me: `session.query(db.mail).filter(db.mail.id.in_(session.query(db.mail.id).join(db.cities, db.cities.zip == db.mail.origin).filter(db.cities.state == 'NY').subquery())).delete(False)`.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error with this.I'd like to make sure I'm not missing something.The 'mail' table doesn't have the 'id' field.                                                               I need to delete all the records from 'mail' where cities.zip = mail.origin and cities.state='NY'.Could you clarify what this is for? filter(db.mail.id.in_(session.query(db.mail.id)

Comment: I was using `id` as the primary key on the table. I suppose this could be done with `origin` instead, but you really should have a primary key for your data.